# How do I edit a Tensorflow dataset in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to build a transformer model for abstractive text summarization task. My dataset is the CNN DM  and I am trying to put the features on pandas DataFrame.

My code:

```
pip install tensorflow_datasets
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

cnn_builder = tfds.summarization.cnn_dailymail.CnnDailymail()
cnn_info = cnn_builder.info
cnn_builder.download_and_prepare()
datasets = cnn_builder.as_dataset()
train_dataset, test_dataset = datasets["train"], datasets["test"]

reviews = pd.DataFrame({'Text':train_dataset['article'] ,'Summary':train_dataset['highlights'] }) 
reviews.head()
```

But the output is :

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-45-2da1e32d8eec> in <module>() ----> 1 reviews = pd.DataFrame({'Text':train_ds['article'] ,'Summary':train_ds['highlights'] }) 2 reviews.head() TypeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

after I fixed the code I got this output. could you please help me to fix this issue !

b"Richard McLuckie, 48, and Stuart Mackenzie-Walker, 51, invented games .\nWon permission from Marmite owner Unilever to use its name and image .\nThen they went on investment TV show to ask for funding from the Dragons .\nBut Unilever contract said entrepreneurs couldn't mention name Marmite .\nThree Dragons pulled out, but Peter Jones and Duncan Bannatyne agreed .\nThey paid the men \xc2\xa350,000 for a 40 per cent stake in board game business ."

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-2da1e32d8eec> in <module>()
----> 1 reviews = pd.DataFrame({'Text':train_ds['article'] ,'Summary':train_ds['highlights'] })
      2 reviews.head()

TypeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as_dataframe` method.

```
reviews = tfds.as_dataframe(train_dataset.take(10))
```

Or you can iterate over the dataset to get `article` and `highlights`:

```
highlights = []
articles = []

for article_highlight in train_dataset.take(10):
  articles.append(article_highlight['article'].numpy())
  highlights.append(article_highlight['highlights'].numpy())

reviews = pd.DataFrame({'Text':articles ,'Summary':highlights })
```

**In your case**, note that `train_dataset.take(10)` will get 10 elements from the dataset.

Comment: thank you @Frightera this code is really helpful :)

Comment: could someone help me please I got this output (   b"Richard McLuckie, 48, and Stuart Mackenzie-Walker, 51, invented games .\\nWon permission from Marmite owner Unilever to use its name and image .\\nThen they went on investment TV show to ask for funding from the Dragons .\\nBut Unilever contract said entrepreneurs couldn\'t mention name Marmite .\\nThree Dragons pulled out, but Peter Jones and Duncan Bannatyne agreed .\\nThey paid the men \\xc2\\xa350,000 for a 40 per cent stake in board game business ." )